# Are the methods of scala.collection.mutable.Stack thread-safe?

Tags: scala, thread-safety, scala-collections

I am worried about the usage of scala.collection.mutable.Stack along multiple threads.

Are the methods push() and pop() of scala.collection.mutable.Stack thread-safe?

And if not what could I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedStack

seems to provide an implementation already.

Comment: But that does mean I have to implemtn my own Stack-Type?